# Outlook add-in - Store and look up data as hidden StorageItem

Tags: c#, vba, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I want to create a *"local database"* in Outlook, by storing some auxiliary data in a hidden form.

After investigating the object model, I found the StorageItem objects, that looked promising.

I managed to store some rows, and also look them up by their unique subject, however, I have trouble iterating through the **StorageItem**s. It says in the object model, that there's no direct iterator available for the StorageItem object, but I could query a **table** from the same folder, that will have the StorageItems.

The table will end up containing 5 items, and none of them look anything like my stored items.

Here's my code that I currently use for inserting the StorageItems with some custom properties:

```
public static void InsertStorageItem(String UniqueID, String Name, String Address) 
{
    Outlook.NameSpace ns = null;
    Outlook.Folder tasksFolder = null;

    ns = outlookApp.Session;
    tasksFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks) as Outlook.Folder;

    Outlook.StorageItem OIEDBTask = tasksFolder.GetStorage(UniqueID, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlStorageIdentifierType.olIdentifyBySubject);

    if (OIEDBTask.Size == 0)
    {
        OIEDBTask.UserProperties.Add("uniqueid", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText);
        OIEDBTask.UserProperties.Add("name", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText);
        OIEDBTask.UserProperties.Add("address", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText);
    }

    //assign values to custom properties
    OIEDBTask.UserProperties["uniqueid"].Value = UniqueID;
    OIEDBTask.UserProperties["name"].Value = Name;
    OIEDBTask.UserProperties["address"].Value = Address;

    OIEDBTask.Save();
}
```

Here's how I would like to query data:

```
public static dynamic QueryStorageItem() 
{
    List<dynamic> QueryResults = new List<dynamic>();
    Outlook.NameSpace ns = null;
    Outlook.Folder tasksFolder = null;
    Outlook.Table ResultTable = null;

    ns = outlookApp.Session;
    tasksFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks) as Outlook.Folder;

    String Filter = "[LastModificationTime] > '5/1/2005'";  //tried removing the filter, but it didn't help. the comparison date is very old, so it should always give back some data
    ResultTable = tasksFolder.GetTable(Filter, Outlook.OlTableContents.olHiddenItems);

    while(!ResultTable.EndOfTable)  //tried a do-while structure also, didn't work.
    {
        Outlook.Row resultRow = ResultTable.GetNextRow();
        QueryResults.Add(resultRow.GetValues()); //the GetValues() function will give me an array with 5 objects in it, that are very different than my StorageItems
    }

    return QueryResults;
}
```

The main idea would be, to use the set up properties of the StorageItems, to use the Filtering, that is given by Outlook: for example, try to find all StorageItems, where the **address** is a certain value.
Naturally, I would write a similar Filter string:

```
String Filter = "[address] = 'certain value'";
```

This doesn't work, and after reading up a little bit on it, I came to the conclusion, that it might not work, because they are custom UserProperties, and filtering should only work on built-in properties for the Outlook items, such as **LastModificationTime** and others.

However, even without filtering, the data set that I get back from the **GetTable** function is of no use. (So I can't iterate through the rows, and they don't represent any data or even structure, that I've inserted)

Any chance somebody could guide towards a better solution?

My main scope is, to store some auxiliary data, that is not visible to the user. If this is not the solution, then I would have to create tasks instead of StorageItems.

Comment: In the absence of any help with StorageItem I would try the following. I would use `Session.Stores.Item(1).FilePath` to get the folder holding the stores (pst and ost files). You could use any folder but this folder seems tidier to me. I would create an Excel workbook in the chosen folder and store my secret data in that.  Excel would give you all the functionality you seek.

Comment: @Laureant: actually, I have found Outlook has a Solutions Module https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692173.aspx

Comment: @SMeaden  I do not understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Storage` (aka associated) items are just regular messages from the MAPI point of view (you can see them in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) if you click IMAPIFolder button and go to the "Associated Contents" tab), it is just OOM decides to expose them very differently. `Storage` items in OOM are not really designed to be searched - the idea is that you create/open your private item by the subject or the message class and do not care or touch other storage items that you know nothing about.

One trick I can think of is to construct message class using the address itself (e.g. "IPM.Note.user@domain.demo") and specify that message class when opening the storage item.

If you really want to search the associated table of contents, Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am also its author) are probably your only choices. Redemption exposes associated items in the same way it exposes the regular items, i.e. [RDOFolder](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOFolder.htm).`HiddentItems` vs [RDOFolder](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOFolder.htm).`Items`. You can then search using [RDOItems](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOItems.htm).`Find/FindNext/Restrict/MAPITable.ExecSQL`.

Comment: Thanks again for the very detailed response, and the time you put into responding to my questions. I can safely say, that the whole Outlook development community is really thankful for your work! I ended up storing my "database" in a subfolder, as tasks, putting all the custom data into custom UserProperties (kind of hidden), and "protecting" the tasks with an event handler, so the end-user won't be able to change them. I did this because I was really stuck with the StorageItems, and I needed a storage ASAP. I will try to look into Redemption afterwards.